# Why isn't stainless steel used for rocket engines?

Tags: rockets, engines, materials

Most people have probably heard by now that Elon is changing Starship to a complete stainless steel build. Anyways, it got me thinking, why isn't stainless steel ever used for rocket engines (nozzle, combustion chamber)?

I am in a University student rocketry club currently building a liquid engine, so this is of particular interest to me. I am on the team designing the regenerative cooling and engine structure/manufacturing.

Copper alloys and [Inconel 718](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconel) (INC718) are popular choices, but what about a 300 series stainless steel?

Compared to INC718, stainless has a slightly lower density, higher specific heat, and higher thermal conductivity. Mechanical properties such as melting temp and modulus of elasticity are similar. The greatest disparity against stainless is that the tensile and yield strength are much smaller than INC718. Is this the primary factor keeping stainless from being used in rocket engines?

Comment: Sutton states it's a usable material. See page 305 https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6cce/fa84a00b396c5b50b66063772f4851392b8f.pdf

Comment: The RS-25 nozzle is made of brazed stainless steel tubes, and at least parts of the turbopumps are made of steel: http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2011/ph240/nguyen1/docs/SSME_PRESENTATION.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the info. Rather than just past examples, what is the practical reason stainless isn't used? I get that it can be used for cooling tubes, but I would tend towards copper for that functionality. For 3D printing (yes, stainless is possible) or the sandwich method (milling channels into the nozzle and attaching an outer jacket) of producing a regeneratively cooled engine, why has stainless steel never been used in the 21st century?

Comment: It would seem to me, the tensile and yield strength mean a nozzle that can constrain and entrain the exhaust will be heavier if made of stainless steel.

Comment: @JCRM I think you are correct that strength is the biggest problem: Asume it got halve the strength that would mean twice the wall thickness required and therefore twice the weight. Moreover twice as thick walls halves the heat conduction so less performance at the same thermal conductivity.

Comment: You need to do a lot more research before you can assert that stainless steel has "never been used in the 21st century". It's realm of application will be limited by thermal conductivity (lower than copper) and temperature range (lower than nickel alloys/etc), but there's certainly areas where it could still be used. And in fact, the Merlin 1A engine is a 21st century counterexample: a Falcon 1 failed due to corrosion of an aluminum nut, and stainless steel components were used to avoid this in later versions.

Comment: The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inconel) has some reasons to use inconel instead of stainless steel. Even for automotive use instead of rocket engines.

Comment: I think the difference is not so much melting points, which are similar, but that steels begin to lose their strength well before melting, whereas inconel does not.

Comment: Not 21st century, but early Atlas rockets used steel for the tanks. Very thin sheet, and the tanks were then pressurized continuously through their use. The rockets would have crumpled without the pressure to support them.

Comment: Also oxidation.

Comment: A very important property is the coefficient of thermal expansion. The higher it is, the more stress is induced where large temperature gradients occur. I suggest to look those coefficients up for the materials you ask about.

Answer (score 4):

First, I am skeptical whether it's actually true true that stainless steel is actually never used in modern rocket engines (as some commments have asked).

Stainless steels in general are not necessarily high performance materials when heated to high temperatures, in either practical strength (including vulnerability to various undesirable heat treatments, embrittlement, fatigue, etc) or in corrosion resistance, surely of some importance when chemically aggressive oxidizers are involved.

This [datasheet for Inconel 718](http://www.specialmetals.com/assets/smc/documents/inconel_alloy_718.pdf) lists the strength, at various temperatures, after various heat treatments.

Some of them are pretty favorable. Additionally, these nickel superalloys are often more chemically resistant, which is probably important when hypergolics are involved.