# What parts of a rocket are particularly cheap or inexpensive?

Tags: launch-vehicle, cost

Related: [What is the most expensive part of a rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35613/32044)

What parts of a launch vehicle, if any, are particularly *inexpensive*?

This can mean "similar in cost to common commercial-grade analogues", "not much of the cost fraction for their size or importance", or "a partially-reusable system, if it jettisoned this part but not others, could save a lot of money".

(I'm looking for components, not materials or individual parts).

Comment: Paint. Insulation foam. H2 and O2.

Comment: @user3528438 Insulation foam for rocket science can't be as cheap as commercial grade foam. Additional quality control and better material properties are not sold for nothing.

Comment: What's the distinction between "components" and "individual parts"?

Comment: @Organic Marble the answer isn't "a socket head cap screw" or "this one pipe manifold".